# CMake error when configuring OpenCV

Tags: opencv, cmake

I am using cmake-gui trying to build opencv but get this error:

```
CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVGenConfig.cmake:134 (math):
  math cannot parse the expression: "8 * ": syntax error, unexpected $end,
  expecting exp_OPENPARENT or exp_NUMBER (4)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:649 (include)
```

This is my first experience with cmake so I am not sure where to turn. I have looked at the OpenCVGenConfig.cmake file but I am clueless about its syntax.  I blew away everything, downloaded the opencv tarball again, but still get the same error. So it does not appear that it is a typo/error in the OpenCVGenConfig.cmake file but in the processing of the "math" command.  I can not seem to find anything relating to a "math" command in the Cmake documentation.

Any ideas?

-Andres

Comment: Which version of CMake are you using?  Ensure you are running the most recent (currently 2.8) to build the current release of OpenCV. Although the docs say an earlier version is ok, some errors can crop up on <2.8.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like the line in question is

```
  math(EXPR SIZEOF_VOID_P_BITS "8 * ${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P}")
```

The problem appears to be that `${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P}` is unset when it should 
indicate the size of a pointer in bytes.  It should get set during the invocation of the `project` command near the start of the top-level CMakeLists.txt.

I'm not sure why it's not being set, it may even be a bug in CMake.  You could try using the [latest version of CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html) (currently 2.8.8) if you're not already.  Also, running CMake from the command line may make a difference (it shouldn't, but you never know).

If this doesn't help, your best bet is to ask for advice on the [CMake mailing list](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/mailing.html).

As an absolute last resort, you could set the appropriate value for `CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P` on your machine by adding

```
  if(NOT CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P)
    set(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P 4)  # replace 4 with 8 for 64-bit machine
  endif()
```

to cmake/OpenCVGenConfig.cmake just before line 134 where the `math` call is made.  This is a horrible hack and I certainly don't recommend it, but it *could* let you build OpenCV while
seeking a proper answer on the mailing list.

You can get info on the `math` command by running

```
cmake --help-command math
```

and on `CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P` by running

```
cmake --help-variable CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P
```

Comment: thank you for your response and suggestions. I will give all of them a try.